# Three JS Warehouse Locations

Tags: three.js

New to learning ThreeJs so I don't just want to use the example I found here [Warehouse Visualization with DataVisual](https://observablehq.com/@mariodelgadosr/warehouse-visualization-with-datavisual)

The data I'm using is from the small warehouse in the link above.

here is the js.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import Papa from "papaparse";

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  10000
);

camera.position.set(-1000, 1000, -500);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5000);
scene.add(axesHelper);

orbit.update();

const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000, 5000);
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xdfdfdf,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);
// plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(5000);
scene.add(gridHelper);
gridHelper.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
scene.rotation.z = -0.5 * Math.PI;
scene.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
scene.position.x = -500;
scene.position.y = -500;
scene.position.z = -500;
renderer.setClearColor(0xdbd2d5);

// Fetch CSV file content
fetch("../data/layout.csv")
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((csvText) => {
    // Parse CSV content using PapaParse
    const parsedData = Papa.parse(csvText, { header: true }).data;
    console.log(parsedData);

    // Create objects for each location
    parsedData.forEach((location) => {
      const x = parseFloat(location.X);
      const y = parseFloat(location.Y);
      const z = parseFloat(location.Z);
      if (!isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y) && !isNaN(z)) {
        const width = parseFloat(location.WIDTH);
        const height = parseFloat(location.HEIGHT);
        const depth = parseFloat(location.DEPTH);

        // Create geometry and material
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0x00aa00,
          wireframe: false,
        });

        // Create mesh
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        cube.position.set(x, y, z);

        // Add cube to the scene
        scene.add(cube);

        var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry); // or WireframeGeometry( geometry )

        var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
          color: 0x000000,
          linewidth: 1,
        });

        var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, mat);

        wireframe.position.set(x, y, z);
        scene.add(wireframe);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching the CSV file:", error);
  });

function animate(time) {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});
```

Issues:

The x,y,z are not drawing correctly. I thought rotating the scene worked, but then whilst it looks at first, the cubes are also the drawn incorrect.

Without rotating the scene, the warehouse locations are drawn vertically.

How can I fit the entire warehouse on the scene/gird (dynamic, based on the data). I've messed about with the position, but not dynamic at all.

How can I fit the scene in the view.

How do I have the box to also draw the box edges. I have achieved here by drawing the box and then the line edges, but that must be wrong.

How can I draw the boxes so the zero is from the bottom of the cube instead of the centre. the first layer of locations go 50% below zero in this example.

Once I've got this part done, I then want to be able to hover over a location and it shows me the location information in a pop up, but need to sort the basics first.